# Kali 2020.3 ModuleNotFound 'ConfigParser' after apt full upgrade

Tags: kali-linux, python

I did a `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y` and received the following error:

```
File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \

File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
```

After reading I think this is related to either a manual fiddling somewhere in `/usr/bin` (Now I have read never to do that, but I can't recall if ever I did in the past...), or something related to the default python version the distro requires.

This is what I can see in terms of the python on the system:
`/usr/bin/python` is a link to `python2`
and `python2` is a link to `python2.7`.

Not sure but is this pointing to the correct version?
Is it even related to the error above?

[image: screen shot with information on system version and python location]

```
sudo apt -f --reinstall install python-configparser

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 62.6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-configparser all 3.5.0b2-3 [62.6 kB]
Fetched 62.6 kB in 1s (57.7 kB/s)            
(Reading database ... 402234 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python-configparser_3.5.0b2-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-configparser (3.5.0b2-3) over (3.5.0b2-3) ...
Setting up mercurial-common (5.4.1-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package mercurial-common (--configure):
 installed mercurial-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-configparser (3.5.0b2-3) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-configparser (--configure):
 installed python-configparser package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mercurial:
 mercurial depends on mercurial-common (= 5.4.1-1); however:
  Package mercurial-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mercurial (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mercurial-common
 python-configparser
 mercurial
```

update 4/august : seems solved.
just an update , after various other forums etc etc.... and doing a lot of experimenting :-). nothing worked.
So tried the apt-cache rdepends commands on all python and python minimal packages and noticed that python2.7 was often showing duplicates in the outputs.
Then tried the dpkg -V and python2 minimal basically gave me a weird output with some ? on the left and mentioned pycompile(sorry did not screenshot that at the time) but it was the only one showing any output and at that time i decided python2.7 was perhaps broken.
So proceeded as follows :
Linked my /usr/bin/ python to python3 like so :  sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python and then,
verified the version to make sure it's pointing somewhere like so :
python --version. Then,
did an aotoremove like so : apt autoremove and,
finally i purged 2.7 minimal like so : sudo apt purge -y python2.7-minimal. finallly I could use apt without any issues. and ,
did a : apt clean and also sudo dpkg --force-all --configure -a and so far everything seems fine.
So I immediately powered off and took a vm snapshot and could start up pretty normal after all that.  Will see if there's a need to reinstall python2.7 later...

ps! Will python forever in the future create these backward compatibility issues ? I noticed quite a lot of problems that seems related to backward compatibility issues while browsing the net for this issue(if so, i think I must drop my plans to learn python as I was really gonna try learn it especially in place of shell scripting, but shoo I don't like the approach I see maybe shell scripting and combo of something like JS or GO will work better in the long term.)

thanks for the tips and help as well guys.. Will update if i run onto 2.7 issues.

Comment: What is the output of `python -V`?

Comment: Since Kali is a rolling release it frequently gets broken package dependencies.  You can try installing `python-configparser` to see of that helps.  If you are really unlucky and this is somehow using python 3 then this could be a regression bug that needs fixing by the maintainers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14087705/453851

Comment: Hi @GAD3R, It shows 2.7.18

Comment: Hi @PhilipCouling Istill get the error. Also noticed that ConfigParser is present in /usr/lib/python2.7 :                                                                                                       ⚡  ls /usr/lib/python2.7 | grep Con 
ConfigParser.py
ConfigParser.pyc

Comment: added ouput of   >>> sudo apt -f --reinstall install python-configparser in OP.

Comment: I also tried sudo update-alternatives --config python & pointed /usr/bin/python to version 3.8 (python -V = 3.8). Still, sudo dpkg --force-all --configure -a :
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-configparser (--configure):
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mercurial-common
 python-configparser

Comment: Any help anyone ? Apt install broken

Comment: see update I made at the bottom of the OP , seems to have helped to purge python2.7-minimal.

Comment: great, so managed to do a new : # sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y and it went smooth, it also reinstalled all the python2.7 minimal, but I left my link pointed to 3.8..